# Is the quality filter for questions customized for MSE?

Tags: support, quality-filter

Is there any evidence that the automatic "quality filter" for questions has been customized for math.stackexchange.com?

Is the filter uniform for the whole network?

Comment: I'm almost certain the quality filter is not customized for each individual site. In particular, it's somewhat easy to write reasonable but dense TeX code that does not pass the quality filter. Fortunately, I've never seen a case where a question with proper background, context, motivation, and attempted work has been rejected.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know if as moderator you have extra information or get to see what is stopped by the filter, but that sounds very plausible.   The filter cannot detect background, context, motivation, and effort, but it can measure length and chattiness, which would explain the fortunate coincidence.

Comment: @mixedmath This is not wat the question is about, but a lot of good answers have been automatically flagged. This is kinda annoying.